# How can I find out what pension formula a new prospective employer uses before joining the company

Tags: canada, employment, pension-plan

I am considering joining as a permanent employee in Canada Pension Plan Investment Board. But I cannot find the pension calculation formula that they use for their retired employees on the [careers page](http://www.cppib.com/en/careers/work-cppib.html). It is a big factor in my decision.

How can I find out how they calculate the pension? Is it 10% of base salary, 20% or 30%? Should I write to the HR? I dont think I will get a response

Comment: If you don't write to HR you definitely won't get a response.

Comment: The formula for their existing retired employees may not be the same formula enjoyed by current or prospective employees. Perhaps you should just ask to see a benefit booklet describing the plan as it currently stands.

Comment: Offer letter ? Many big companies lay it out on the offer letters.